# How can I get the statistic value like p-value and out-put like residual series from pmdarima.auto_arima()?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using pmdarima.auto_arima to estimate arima model, I can only check the out-put in console by stepwise_fit.summary().

1. How can I find the estimated value, or the residual of the model.
2. Is there any way I can read the statistic value like t-value, p-value and the estimated value like residual series in the variable window?

import pmdarima as pm
stepwise_fit = pm.auto_arima(log_unr, error_action = 'ignore', supress_warnings = True, stepwise = True)
stepwise_fit.summary()

I expected to get a tuple-like variable in the variable window which includes the out put. But the actual output is in the console.